# Textual Commitment

Tags: computational-linguistics, nlp, english

I am working on question answering problem. The major task is to understand text and convert complex sentences to simpler sentences i.e Textual Commitments using Conventional implicature and conversational implicature and Supplemental Expressions, Relation Extraction:

Example of textual Commitment can be found at http://pastebin.com/kF2R3tGg

I want to implement a practical Textual Commitment system. I will be glad if you can provide me with headstart on this  by providing any existing tools or any reference which can provide me with rules-sets which can be implemented to decompose such sentences in textual commitment.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but when I looked at the sample collection of textual commitments, I noticed that one pretty important thing seems to be missing: the name of the ship IS Harriet Lane! Or isn't that strongly enough entailed?

Comment: I also noticed that there are no statements that a White House hostess is female and is a human being. This may fall out from something else, but even a complete list of such TCs seems to be only one part of the system. One needs a complete list of entailment rules as well, to see whether either list is complete.

Answer (score 1):

On the free software side you may want to look at the plethora of tools available from [The Semantic Software Lab](http://www.semanticsoftware.info/) at Concordia University.

If you are interested in commercial work in this area, take a look at [Using Discourse Commitments to Recognize Textual Entailment](http://aclweb.org/anthology-new/C/C08/C08-1043.pdf) or [A Discourse Commitment-Based Framework for Recognizing Textual
Entailment](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1660000/1654571/p171-hickl.pdf?ip=131.187.117.22&acc=OPEN&CFID=68247862&CFTOKEN=68115021&__acm__=1330466398_ce12947a2778afa0a654f6133de24201for) as references, and the (commercial) software tools from [Language Computer Corp.](http://www.languagecomputer.com/) They have [demos of some of their tools](http://www.languagecomputer.com/labs.html). I have not used these tools.